# Como enviar arquivo XML WS da Porto Seguro (feito em PHP) usando RestSharp C#

Tags: php, c#, xml, http-request, restsharp

Estou tentando integrar um arquivo XML Ct-e com o Web Service da Porto Seguro (feito em PHP) usando RestSharp em C# e sempre retorna mensagem dizendo que não conseguiram abrir o XML  ou que arquivo está vazio.
Mesmo colocando o mesmo código fornecido pelo Postman usa e não dá certo, parece que o problema está na forma que envio o arquivo, pois eles retornam erro como
se o tamanho do arquivo estivesse zero. Enviando pelo Postman dá certo.

Queria ver se alguém já teve esse problema ao fazer a integração de arquivo XML CT-e para averbação por meio no Web Service JSON da Porto Seguro.

Abaixo está exemplo de código mínimo com as minhas tentativas e retorno recebido, como também o link do manual da porto seguro.

Ja fiz várias tentativas de maneiras diferentes de incluir esse XML na request e sem sucesso. Espero que consigam me ajudar. Obrigado.

**Código**

```cs
 // CÓDIGO
public static void testeIntegracaoRest()
{ 
    var link = "https://www.averbeporto.com.br/websys/php/conn.php";
    var client = new RestClient(link);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    var parametros = @"mod=login&comp=5&user=00234567000122&pass=0023";

    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", parametros, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    var login = client.Execute(request);

    if (login.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // continua
        var cookies = login.Cookies;

        var restResponseCookie = new RestResponseCookie();
        restResponseCookie = cookies[0];

        client = new RestClient("https://www.averbeporto.com.br/websys/php/conn.php");
        request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddCookie(restResponseCookie.Name, restResponseCookie.Value);

        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");

        byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml");

        request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"comp\"\r\n\r\n5\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mod\"\r\n\r\nUpload\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"path\"\r\n\r\neguarda/php/\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; " +
            "filename=\"C:\\XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml"\r\nContent-Type: " + "application/xml\r\n\r\n\r\n" +
            "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dump\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n",
            ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
}
```

**Retorno WS**

```js
 // RETORNO WS

 {"success":1,"S":{"P":0,"D":0,"R":0,"N":1},"prot":null,"error":{"msg":"Error opening XML","code":"03"},"dump":{"POST":{"comp":"5","mod":"Upload","path":"\/var\/www\/averbeporto.com.br\/web\/websys\/eguarda\/php\/","dump":"1","v":2,"ext":".php"},"COOKIE":{"portal":{"ses":"e002f119bb4d854b96ebd9c4c85b84f7"}},"FILES":{"file":{"name":"XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml","type":"application\/xml","tmp_name":"\/var\/www\/clients\/client0\/web124\/tmp\/phpqspsPj","error":0,"size":0}}}}
```

```
 // LINK MANUAL PORTO SEGURO

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1da005UzBF1Wzm8LmiB4JJnaXaLXtFKgl6S_rErMlXF8/edit
```

Comment: Quando faz `"filename=\"" + array +...` você está informando que o nome do arquivo é o conteúdo em XML dentro de `array`. Ou você sobe o arquivo  `C:\XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml` e faz  `"filename=\"" + [URL do Arquivo no Servidor]+...` ou então procura na API Porto Seguro um campo para colocar esses dados.

Comment: Também já fiz esse teste, não funcionou

Comment: E se você subir o arquivo e trocar essa linha `""filename=\""..."` por essa aqui:
`"------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"[URL do Arquivo no Servidor];Content-Type: " + "application/xml\"; " +`

Comment: @Augusto, fiz essa alteração, mas retorna do WS da Porto Seguro como se não tivesse adicionado arquivo nenhum a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foi resolvido ao não utilizar o RestSharp.

```
public async void Testar()
    {

        var link = "https://www.averbeporto.com.br/websys/php/conn.php";
        var client = new RestClient(link);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        var parametros = @"mod=login&comp=5&user=00234567000122&pass=0023";

        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", parametros, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var login = client.Execute(request);
        var restResponseCookie = new RestResponseCookie();
        if (login.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var cookies = login.Cookies;


            restResponseCookie = cookies[0];
        }


        System.Net.WebClient oWeb = new System.Net.WebClient();

        oWeb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        oWeb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, restResponseCookie.Name + "=" + restResponseCookie.Value);
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("comp", "5");
        parameters.Add("mod", "Upload");
        parameters.Add("path", "eguarda/php/");
        parameters.Add("dump", "1");
        parameters.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        oWeb.QueryString = parameters;

        var responseBytes = oWeb.UploadFile(link, @"C:\Teste\XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml");
        string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de fazer todo esse processo você pode simplesmente usar o método `addFile`
ex:

```
if (login.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // continua
        var cookies = login.Cookies;

        var restResponseCookie = new RestResponseCookie();
        restResponseCookie = cookies[0];

        client = new RestClient("https://www.averbeporto.com.br/websys/php/conn.php");
        request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddCookie(restResponseCookie.Name, restResponseCookie.Value);
        restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request..AddFile("content", "C:\\XML0702794600019004-05-20188001.xml");

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

Comment: E os campos `comp`, `mod`, `file`, `path` e `dump` como que ele passa nessa requisição?

Comment: só alterei o dentro do if para dar o exemplo, o resto voce já setou lá em cima, é só manter

Comment: Foi a primeira tentantiva, mas fazendo dessa forma com addFile retorna do WS da porto seguro como se não tivesse nenhum arquivo na request, então tentei copiar exatamente o código do Postman que nele funciona corretamente, por isso está dessa forma. E referente ao comp, mod, file, path e dump?